# Environment variables in ec2 don't show up with sudo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an ec2 instance running a node application.

If I run my application with just `nodemon app.js`. The environment variables I set in the Ec2 instance's .bashrc are picked up by my application as expected. If I run with `sudo` they disappear into the wind, never to be seen again. In all seriousness, where do they go and how do I make sure they appear?

Comment: When you say "the EC2 instance's .bashrc" you are probably referring to the ec2-user account's .bashrc. Is the .bashrc file in `/home/ec2-user`? When you run something with sudo you are running it as `root` instead of `ec2-user`. You probably need to edit `/etc/profile` instead, which will apply to all user accounts on the system.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sudo`, you are actually starting a new environment as the `root` user, so any environment variables that exist in your current shell will not be passed. There are three ways to get around this.

**1. Tell sudo to preserve environment**

The sudo has a handy argument `-E` or `--preserve-env` which will pass all your environment variables into the sudo environment.

**2. Passing only the variables you need**

A better approach is to just pass the environment variables you want to need to preserve, instead of passing everything. There are two ways to accomplish this, first you can supply a list of environment variable names to the `--preserve-env` argument. For example:

> sudo --preserve-env=HOME /usr/bin/env

Finally you can also set environment variables directly in the sudo command, like this:

> sudo ZEBRA=true /usr/bin/env

Note, we are using the /usr/bin/env command above, which simply echo's all the environment variables.

**3. Store your environment variables either in `/root/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`**

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer to my question. The answer above seems sufficient. The quick answer is:
Simplistically, when you run sudo, you're running as a superuser/root, not ec2 user. So the variables are not available. In order to make them available, I echo them like so.

`sudo ENV_VAR=$(sudo echo $ENV_VAR_IN_BASHRC) PORT=443 NODE_ENV=production forever start ./`

It works for me.